# react hook form - watch vs onchange , which one would be the right approach

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, watch, react-hook-form

I am using `watch`,`setValue` and `getValues` to update one dropdown selected value based on another dropdown selected value.
It can be also done using dropdown list's `onChange` so, `onChange`, `setValue` and `getValues` so no need to use of `watch`.
Can you please guide, `watch` is performance cost then using `onChange` or it will be fine with watch how its implemented below (without `onChange`).

```
const dropdownList_1_watch_value = watch(dropdownList_1);

    useEffect(()=>{
    if (dropdownList_1_watch_value !== 'specificValue') && getValues(dropdownListControlName) !== defaultValue)
    {
    setValue(another_dropdownListControlName, defaultValue);
    }},[dropdownList_1_watch_value]);

return (
<>
 // list of dropdown list components and other controls
</>

);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance there shouldn't be much of a difference between those to.

I will cite from a blog post:

> React Watcher should be used sparingly, in cases where you can't
> really solve the problem any other way. In most cases, where you need
> to do something when some prop changes, you don't really need it. Why?
> Because in most cases you can usually trigger the event together with
> the action with caused the prop to be changed, e.g. when triggering a
> filtering change on a listing.

Full post: http://sborrazas.com/blog/react-watcher

Comment: Thanks for comments. Using this Watch , https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch . Not sure, which one better to go with, onChange combobox will also provide current latest value.